# How to add colour to overview tabs in EVE?

Tags: eve-online

In the Overview Settings where I can set the Overview tab names all I see is the ability to set Tab Names and not colour.

[image]

In the below screenshot, someone has customized their Overview to have tabs with colour - how can I also do this?

[image: Overview tabs with different colours]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To color the UI together you can go to the option menu, press escape within the game. The "general settings" tab has color and opacity sliders.

[image]

You cannot change each window independently however. If things do not seem to work out, try to pin/unpin or reopen windows. There where some bugs related to this back when i played but these should be fixed by now.

---

To color individual tabs you have the ability to HTML code it all within the "TAB NAME" section. For instance if you fill `<color=0xffE50000>PVP</color>` at the "TAB NAME" your overview tab title will be PVP colored in red.

You first need to lookup the color code that you want to use. There are plenty of tools around, you can also look for color code tables on google like this one:

[image]

Then you have to paste that code between the tags of the code above. `<color=0xffXXXXXX>title</color>` paste the color code over the `XXXXXX` and fill in the title you want to show between the opening and `</closing>` tag.

You can take this a little step further by adding more .

- `<b>title</b>` Makes the title bold.
- `<i>title</i>` Makes the title italic
- `<u>title</u>` Gives the title an under strike.
- `<fontsize=XX>title</fontsize>` changes font size.

You can combine these tags however you want, but the first tag you put should close the last, well that is just good practice in case you ever want to build "good" web pages.

```
<color=0xff00FF00><b><fontsize=14>Awesome formatted tab title</fontsize></b></color>
```